# Getting line number of input file which is not coming in final output

Tags: perl

I have shown here a small sample Perl script section like as below where from a input file based on many if-else condition getting final output in the @final_records. My questions is how to easily detect the input file line numbers which are getting rejected in this code and possibly taking those lines in a separate new file ?

```
while (<MY_INP_FILE>) {
    chomp;
    next if $_ =~ /^(NAME)/;
    (   $secname,       $id_my_sec_num_des,
        $my_source,     $id_my_sec_num_src,
        $id_my_unique,  $security_typ,
        $my_sector_des, $id_my_global,
        $composite_id_my_global,
    ) = split( /\|/, $_ );

    if ( exists $trexcp{$id_my_global} ) {
        $my_match_ticker = $trexcp{$id_my_global};
    }
    else {

        $ticker          = $id_my_sec_num_des;
        $my_match_ticker = $id_my_sec_num_des;

        if ( $my_sector_des eq "BSE" ) {
            ( $indx_tick, $indx_val ) = split( ' ', $id_my_sec_num_des );
            $my_match_ticker = $indx_tick;

        }
        elsif ( $my_sector_des eq "PFD" || $my_sector_des eq "COMP" ) {
            ( $base_ticker, $div_percent, $matdt, $series )
                = split( " ", $id_my_sec_num_des );

            if ( length($base_ticker) > 3 ) {
                $base_tick = substr( $base_ticker, 0, 3 );
            }
            else { $base_tick = $base_ticker; }

            if ( $my_sector_des eq "PFD" && $matdt ne "" ) {
                $series =~ s /([A-Z])([A-Z])/$2/;
                $my_match_ticker = $base_tick . ".PR" . $series;
            }

        }
        elsif ( $my_sector_des eq "EQ" ) {

            if ( $my_source =~ m/^(BD|IN|MM|KS|KF|SP)$/ ) {
                if ( $my_source eq "MM" ) {
                    $my_match_ticker =~ s/(\s+)/ /g;
                    @mm_tick = split( ' ', $my_match_ticker );

                    if (   ( $my_match_ticker !~ /\*/ )
                        && ( $#mm_tick eq 2 )
                        && ( $mm_tick[2] ne " " ) )
                    {
                        $my_match_ticker = "$mm_tick[0]" . "$mm_tick[2]";
                    }
                    $my_match_ticker =~ s/\*|\///g;
                }
            }
            elsif (( $my_source eq "HK" )
                && ( length($id_my_sec_num_des) < 4 ) )
            {
                if ( $id_my_sec_num_des =~ m/^(\d\d\d)$/ ) {
                    $my_match_ticker
                        =~ s/$id_my_sec_num_des/0$id_my_sec_num_des/;
                }

            }

        }
    }

    $final_my_records = join(
        "|",
        (   $id_my_global,           $id_my_sec_num_src,
            $id_my_unique,           $secname,
            $id_my_sec_num_des,      $my_source,
            $security_typ,           $my_sector_des,
            $composite_id_my_global, $my_match_ticker
        )
    );

    push @final_records, "$final_my_records\n";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`$.` variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_LINE_NUMBER)

> - **`HANDLE->input_line_number( EXPR )`**
> - **`$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER`**
> - **`$NR`**
> - **`$.`**
>
> Current line number for the last filehandle accessed.
>
> Each filehandle in Perl counts the number of lines that have been
>   read from it. (Depending on the value of `$/`, Perl's idea of what
>   constitutes a line may not match yours.) When a line is read from
>   a filehandle (via `readline()` or `<>`), or when `tell()` or
>   `seek()` is called on it, `$.` becomes an alias to the line counter
>   for that filehandle.
>
> You can adjust the counter by assigning to `$.`, but this will not
>   actually move the seek pointer. Localizing `$.` will not localize
>   the filehandle's line count. Instead, it will localize perl's
>   notion of which filehandle `$.` is currently aliased to.
>
> `$.` is reset when the filehandle is closed, but not when an open
>   filehandle is reopened without an intervening `close()`. For more
>   details, see "I/O Operators" in `perlop`. Because `<>` never does an
>   explicit close, line numbers increase across `ARGV` files (but see
>   examples in `eof` in `perlfunc`).
>
> You can also use `HANDLE->input_line_number(EXPR)` to access the
>   line counter for a given filehandle without having to worry about
>   which handle you last accessed.
>
> Mnemonic: many programs use `.` to mean the current line number.

The code which add record `push @final_records, "$final_my_records\n";` is outside of all the you spaghetti if-else code. It means the only place where is record rejected is `next if $_ =~ /^(NAME)/;`. So do something like:

```
if ( /^(NAME)/ ) {
    ... # put your code here
    next;
}
```

Comment: ..if ( /^(NAME)/ ) has been used to by pass the header row of file. I have thought a new approach. I will put a print "$. ,\n"; just after chomp and fill an array1. Then just before  $final_my_records = join(  I will put one more print "$. ,\n"; and fill an array2. The difference of array1(all lines)and 2(selected lines) should be the rejected line numbers. Could you agree/help this construction ?

Comment: Operation `push` is done for all lines which pass `/^(NAME)/` test. I do not understand you. There is not any other code which skips lines.

Comment: @Hynek...sir I have just posted code snippets so there might be {} related mistake. Fact is if Input file has 100000 line output is 80000 line. I needed those 20000 line for analysis purpose. Anyway Thanks for your help and I have accepted your answer and my idea is working.